# Saving user information in MVC (Show same data on different views)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I could use some help in order to find the best way of saving data a user selects during a mini booking site.

Right now my booking flow contains of 4 steps (4 views). Each of these 4 views has it's own Model linked.

Lets say that on the first page, I am saving information like departure / return date and so on. That information is stored in a model. How can I the best way pass this information to the other models? I don't think creating a viewmodel containing of all 4 models in the end is a good solution.

What I have tried to do, is to create a class which can hold the data. Before going to the next step, I am saving the data to this class and storing the needed data in the next Model.

The scenario looks like this:

- Storing data to choices class using step 1 Model (BookingModel)
- Sending necessary data from choices class to new Model (RoutesModel) before showing the view.
- Storing data to choices class using step 2 Model (RoutesModel)
- Sending necessary data from choices class to new Model (TpaModel) before showing the view.

and so on...

---

Right now I can save the data to the choices class in step 1, but when I try to send the data to the other Models, it fails because the fields inside choices are empty.

```
public class Choices
{      
    public DateTime Departuredate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Returndate { get; set; }      
}
```

**How I load the data and creating a model for the controller on step 2:**

**RoutesController (step 2):**

```
 // GET: Routes
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _routeModelService.CreateRouteModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Helper class that creates RoutesModel**

```
public class RouteModelService
{
    private Choices _Choices;

    public RouteModelService()
    {
        _Choices = new Choices();
    }

    public RouteModel CreateRouteModel(RouteModel model = null)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new RouteModel()
            {

            };

            model.DepartureDate = _Choices.Departuredate;
            model.ReturnDate = _Choices.Returndate;

        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Is it because I create a new instants of choices that its empty?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't do this on one page (and show/hide each step in the 'wizard'). And why is each step a different controller? (and yes, unless you pass an instance of `Choices` with the correct values set, the `DepartureDate` and `ReturnDate` will be the default `DateTime.MinValue`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but how can I create an instants of choices in my RouteModelService class which actually contains the values?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to make a simple exercise complicated, but your method needs to be `public RouteModel CreateRouteModel(DateTime departureDate, DateTime ReturnDate)` - i.e. pass the values to the method so you can set them